# why I am getting the "ValueError: axes don't match array" when trying test the model in tensorflow for Speech emotion Recognition

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, speech-recognition

I am working on SER with model TIMNET. The main coed is here:

authors of the code provided pretrained models and what you have to do is copy and paste the command they provided in the terminal. for my working purpose I copied all the py files and edited them slightly so that i can run them in colab. here is my edited code Modal.py where the test method lives:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer,Dense,Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
# from Common_Model import Common_Model
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import copy

# from TIMNET import TIMNET


def smooth_labels(labels, factor=0.1):
    # smooth the labels
    labels *= (1 - factor)
    labels += (factor / labels.shape[1])
    return labels

class WeightLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WeightLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1],1),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)  
        super(WeightLayer, self).build(input_shape)  
 
    def call(self, x):
        tempx = tf.transpose(x,[0,2,1])
        x = K.dot(tempx,self.kernel)
        x = tf.squeeze(x,axis=-1)
        return  x
 
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0],input_shape[2])
    
def softmax(x, axis=-1):
    ex = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True))
    return ex/K.sum(ex, axis=axis, keepdims=True)

class TIMNET_Model(Common_Model):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, class_label, **params):
        super(TIMNET_Model,self).__init__(**params)
        # self.args = args
        self.data_shape = input_shape
        self.num_classes = len(class_label)
        self.class_label = class_label
        self.matrix = []
        self.eva_matrix = []
        self.acc = 0
        print("TIMNET MODEL SHAPE:",input_shape)
    
    # nb_filters=64,
      # kernel_size=2,
      # nb_stacks=1,
      # dilations=None,
      # activation = "relu",
      # dropout_rate=0.1,
      # return_sequences=True,
    
    def create_model(self):
        self.inputs=Input(shape = (self.data_shape[0],self.data_shape[1]))
        self.multi_decision = TIMNET(nb_filters=64,
                                kernel_size=2,
                                nb_stacks=1,
                                dilations=10,
                                activation = "relu",
                                dropout_rate=0.1,
                                return_sequences=True, 
                                name='TIMNET')(self.inputs)

        self.decision = WeightLayer()(self.multi_decision)
        self.predictions = Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax')(self.decision)
        self.model = Model(inputs = self.inputs, outputs = self.predictions)
        
        self.model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
                           optimizer =Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.93, beta_2=0.98, epsilon=1e-8),
                           metrics = ['accuracy'])
        print("Temporal create succes!")
        
    def train(self, x, y):

        filepath = self.args.model_path
        resultpath = self.args.result_path

        if not os.path.exists(filepath):
            os.mkdir(filepath)
        if not os.path.exists(resultpath):
            os.mkdir(resultpath)

        i=1
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(now,'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        kfold = KFold(n_splits=self.args.split_fold, shuffle=True, random_state=self.args.random_seed)
        avg_accuracy = 0
        avg_loss = 0
        for train, test in kfold.split(x, y):
            self.create_model()
            y_train = smooth_labels(copy.deepcopy(y[train]), 0.1)
            folder_address = filepath+self.args.data+"_"+str(self.args.random_seed)+"_"+now_time
            if not os.path.exists(folder_address):
                os.mkdir(folder_address)
            weight_path=folder_address+'/'+str(self.args.split_fold)+"-fold_weights_best_"+str(i)+".hdf5"
            checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(weight_path, verbose=1, save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=False)
            max_acc = 0
            best_eva_list = []
            h = self.model.fit(x[train], y_train,validation_data=(x[test],  y[test]),batch_size = self.args.batch_size, epochs = self.args.epoch, verbose=1,callbacks=[checkpoint])
            self.model.load_weights(weight_path)
            best_eva_list = self.model.evaluate(x[test],  y[test])
            avg_loss += best_eva_list[0]
            avg_accuracy += best_eva_list[1]
            print(str(i)+'_Model evaluation: ', best_eva_list,"   Now ACC:",str(round(avg_accuracy*10000)/100/i))
            i+=1
            y_pred_best = self.model.predict(x[test])
            self.matrix.append(confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y[test],axis=1),np.argmax(y_pred_best,axis=1)))
            em = classification_report(np.argmax(y[test],axis=1),np.argmax(y_pred_best,axis=1), target_names=self.class_label,output_dict=True)
            self.eva_matrix.append(em)
            print(classification_report(np.argmax(y[test],axis=1),np.argmax(y_pred_best,axis=1), target_names=self.class_label))

        print("Average ACC:",avg_accuracy/self.args.split_fold)
        self.acc = avg_accuracy/self.args.split_fold
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(resultpath+self.args.data+'_'+str(self.args.split_fold)+'fold_'+str(round(self.acc*10000)/100)+"_"+str(self.args.random_seed)+"_"+now_time+'.xlsx')
        for i,item in enumerate(self.matrix):
            temp = {}
            temp[" "] = self.class_label
            for j,l in enumerate(item):
                temp[self.class_label[j]]=item[j]
            data1 = pd.DataFrame(temp)
            data1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(i), encoding='utf8')

            df = pd.DataFrame(self.eva_matrix[i]).transpose()
            df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(i)+"_evaluate", encoding='utf8')
        writer.save()
        writer.close()

        K.clear_session()
        self.matrix = []
        self.eva_matrix = []
        self.acc = 0
        self.trained = True
    
    def test(self, x, y, path):
        i=1
        kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=16)
        avg_accuracy = 0
        avg_loss = 0
        x_feats = []
        y_labels = []
        for train, test in kfold.split(x, y):
            self.create_model()
            print("ok1")
            weight_path=path +"/"+"10-fold_weights_best_"+str(i)+".hdf5"
            print("ok1")
            self.model.fit(x[train], y[train],validation_data=(x[test],  y[test]),batch_size = 64,epochs = 0,verbose=0)
            print("ok1")
            self.model.load_weights(weight_path)#+source_name+'_single_best.hdf5')
            print("ok1")
            weightsss = self.model.load_weights(weight_path)#+source_name+'_single_best.hdf5')
            print("ok1")
            best_eva_list = self.model.evaluate(x[test],  y[test])
            avg_loss += best_eva_list[0]
            avg_accuracy += best_eva_list[1]
            print(str(i)+'_Model evaluation: ', best_eva_list,"   Now ACC:",str(round(avg_accuracy*10000)/100/i))
            i+=1
            y_pred_best = self.model.predict(x[test])
            self.matrix.append(confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y[test],axis=1),np.argmax(y_pred_best,axis=1)))
            em = classification_report(np.argmax(y[test],axis=1),np.argmax(y_pred_best,axis=1), target_names=self.class_label,output_dict=True)
            self.eva_matrix.append(em)
            print(classification_report(np.argmax(y[test],axis=1),np.argmax(y_pred_best,axis=1), target_names=self.class_label))
            caps_layer_model = Model(inputs=self.model.input,
            outputs=self.model.get_layer(index=-2).output)
            feature_source = caps_layer_model.predict(x[test])
            x_feats.append(feature_source)
            y_labels.append(y[test])
        print(weightsss)
        print("Average ACC:",avg_accuracy/10)
        self.acc = avg_accuracy/10
        return x_feats, y_labels
```

here is tester code:

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/Code/MFCC/IEMOCAP.npy",allow_pickle=True).item()
x_source = data["x"]
y_source = data["y"]
# CLASS_LABELS = CLASS_LABELS_dict[args.data]

print(x_source.shape[1:])

model = TIMNET_Model(input_shape=x_source.shape[1:], class_label="IEMOCAP")
model.test(x_source, y_source, path="/content/drive/MyDrive/Code/Test_Models/IEMOCAP_16")
```

when i try to exceute model.test it give me error  axes don't match array and it occurs in the line `self.model.load_weights(weight_path)` (after 3 ok1 print). the paths are accurate but i cant resolve the problem x_source has the accurate input shape. you can visit my colab notebook if you want: [text](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iSuwUPUHbeGCCEkPUSt5CsTnryI2V2ZT?usp=sharing)

Comment: sorry for the mistake :
main code is in here: https://github.com/Jiaxin-Ye/TIM-Net_SER/tree/main

Comment: my colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iSuwUPUHbeGCCEkPUSt5CsTnryI2V2ZT?usp=sharing